# Show amount of open orders per customer

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck for a while on a piece of code of which I can't find the solution.. Tried a whole bunch of options but none of it seems to work.

I have a table with all my customers. Its showing their name, postcode etc. But I also want to show the amount of open orders in the same table.

I got these tables mysql tables:

TABLE 1

Tablename: customer

Columns: customer_ID, postcode, customer_since, customer_name

TABLE 2

Tablename: status

Columsn: status_ID, status_name

TABLE 3

Tablename: orders

Columns: order_ID, customer_ID, status_ID

So far this is my code:

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT customer.customer_ID, customer.postcode, customer.since, customer.name
FROM customer
ORDER BY customer.customer_ID desc  ");

echo '<table border="0" width="515"  >
      <tr>
    <td>
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="515" id="table1" >
         <tr>
            <th width="60" align="center"><span class="tabledescription">Number:</span></td> //customernumber
        <th width="155" align="center"><span class="tabledescription">Name:</span></td> //customername
        <th width="100" align="center"><span class="tabledescription">Postcode:</span></td>//customerpostcode
        <th width="100" align="center"><span class="tabledescription">Orders open:</span></td>//amount of open orders
        <th width="100" align="center"><span class="tabledescription">Since:</span></td>//customer since
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="width:565px; height:322px; overflow:auto;">
         <table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="575" >';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$id = $row['customer_ID'];
$name= $row['name'];
$postcode = $row['postcode'];
$status = $row['status'];
$since = $row['customer_since'];
$probleem = $row['probleem'];

$csince = date('d-m-Y', $since);

echo "<tr><td width=64><a style=' color: #009bce; text-decoration: none;' href='detailvieuwcustomer.php?id=".$id."'>".$id."</a></td>
        <td width=160>$name</td>
        <td width=105>$postcode</td>
        <td width=105>amount</td>
        <td width=105>$csince</td></tr>";

        }
echo ' </table>  
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

So far that is working and showing my 8 customers at this moment. I have 7 different status types for each order. The last one is that its delivered so that one isn't open. I made this code:

```
$statusnumber = 7;


$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order WHERE customer_ID = '". $id . " ' AND status_ID != '". $statusnumber . "' ");

while($prow = mysql_fetch_array($sql1, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

$openstatus = $prow['storing_ID'];

echo $openstatus;
```

This one is showing me every order which doesn't has status_ID 7.

Now I don't know how to count the number of orders which got status_ID 1 - 6 and put the amount of open orders in the table behind the right customer.

I also tried to join the tables:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT status.status_ID, order.status_ID, order.customer_ID, customer.customer_ID, customer.name, customer.postcode, customer.since
        FROM order
        INNER JOIN status on (status.status_ID = order.status_ID)
        INNER JOIN customer on (customer.customer_ID = order.customer_customer_ID)
        ORDER BY customer.customer_ID desc ");
```

But when I do that its showing me all my customers multiple times, because he's getting the customer_ID from orders, and I got around 30 orders. Its giving me a result like: 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5 etc.

I just can't seem to display all customers 1 time with the right amount of orders they have open..

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: `GROUP BY customer.customer_ID` ?

Comment: Worked for me Geo, altough it only shows the me customers that placed an order. Not the ons that got 0 orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches.

One is to do an OUTER JOIN to the `order` table. The trick here is the GROUP BY on the customer_ID, and doing a check on the `status_ID` column to return either a 0 or a 1, and then adding up the 0s and 1s with a SUM group aggregate function:

```
 SELECT c.customer_ID
      , c.postcode
      , c.since
      , c.name
      , SUM(IF(s.status_ID != 7,1,0)) AS open_order_count
  FROM customer c
  LEFT
  JOIN order o
    ON o.customer_ID = c.customer_ID
  LEFT
  JOIN status s
    ON s.status_ID = o.status_ID
 GROUP
    BY c.customer_ID
     , c.postcode
     , c.since
     , c.name
 ORDER
    BY c.customer_ID DESC
```

NOTE: we could use a `COUNT` aggregate in place of the `SUM`, but we would need to return a NULL for those rows we didn't want to count...

```
      , COUNT(IF(s.status_ID != 7,1,NULL)) AS open_order_count
```

---

Another approach (usually less performant on large sets), is to use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list:

```
 SELECT c.customer_ID
      , c.postcode
      , c.since
      , c.name
      , ( SELECT SUM(IF(s.status_ID != 7,1,0))
            FROM order o
            LEFT
            JOIN status s
              ON s.status_ID = o.status_ID
           WHERE o.customer_ID = c.customer_ID
        ) AS open_order_count
  FROM customer c
 ORDER BY c.customer_ID DESC
```

---

NOTE: For performance, I would probably avoid the join to the `status` table, and shortcut the check on `status_ID` by looking at just the `order` table. (It really depends on why the `status` table is being included in the query; I just don't see a need for it here.) e.g.

```
 SELECT c.customer_ID
      , c.postcode
      , c.since
      , c.name
      , ( SELECT SUM(IF(o.status_ID != 7,1,0))
            FROM order o
           WHERE o.customer_ID = c.customer_ID
        ) AS open_order_count
  FROM customer c
 ORDER BY c.customer_ID DESC
```

---

Another approach is to use an inline view to get the open order counts for all customers, and then join that to the customer table...

```
 SELECT c.customer_ID
      , c.postcode
      , c.since
      , c.name
      , IFNULL(r.open_order_count,0) AS open_order_count
  FROM customer c
  LEFT
  JOIN (
         SELECT o.customer_ID
              , SUM(IF(o.status_ID != 7,1,0)) AS open_order_count
           FROM order o
          GROUP
             BY o.customer_ID
       ) r
    ON r.customer_ID = o.customer_ID
 ORDER BY c.customer_ID DESC
```

Comment: in your last block you are using r.open_order_count and r.customer_ID.. what is the r used for in that case?

Comment: Your first solution worked for me, thank you very much. Altough I still have 1 question. It isn't showing any customers that don't have any orders. I also which to add those. Its like a full customer list with like a quickvieuw of the open orders. Thank you already for what you've done.

Comment: @Phatorax: `r` is the alias assigned to the inline view (the subquery), so `r.customer_ID` in the outer query references the column returned by the inline view.  The LEFT JOIN operators in the queries should be returning all rows from the `customer` table, along with any related `order`, if any. (That's what an OUTER join does for us.)

Comment: I understand, thank you for the explanation. Got it working now, used the wrong join. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question:

1. **How do I know when orders are open or not?** Relying on "status IDs 1-6" is not usually the right approach. What happens when you add another status? Now "open" means "status IDs 1-6 and 8?" You can see this gets out of hand quickly. The better approach is to add an `is_open` flag to the `status` table (probably to the `order` table too, but that's just for historical purposes and may not be necessary in your application).
2. **How do I get a count of open orders for each customer?** Well the answer to this question depends on your solution to the previous, but this should do the trick (assuming you have added an is_open column to your status table which is a TINYINT(1) and set the flag correctly on each of the order statuses):

   SELECT
     status.status_ID,
     order.status_ID,
     order.customer_ID,
     customer.customer_ID,
     customer.name,
     customer.postcode,
     customer.since,
     COUNT(DISTINCT IF(status.is_open = 1, order.order_ID, NULL)) AS open_orders
   FROM customer
     LEFT JOIN order ON (order.customer_ID = customer.customer_ID)
     LEFT JOIN status ON (status.status_ID = order.status_ID)
   GROUP BY customer.customer_ID

Notice the use of a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` so that customers will show up in your customer list with or without an active order.

Comment: A flag is a column like any other column. You just make a `TINYINT(1)` field on your status table that indicates if that status is an open status or not (if the field's value is 1, the status is open - if not, it's closed).

Comment: I understand now. Thank you, but I prefer not to make unnecessary columns in my database. I got it working now in my php file. Think your solution would work as well, but its not the solution I was looking for. Thanks again.